# How do I prevent Excel from merging a row's data into a single cell when pasting?

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have two spreadsheets that I'm copying rows between. I have a macro that is in a separate workbook that stays open while I open and close the source and target workbooks which contain the spreadsheets.

I'll select the target row with

```
rows(activecell.row).copy
```

I'll then close the source workbook because its name is identical to the target workbook, open the target workbook in a different folder and execute

```
activesheet.pastespecial ' this line copied from record macro generated code
```

Sometimes it'll work fine, other times the source row will get scrunched into the first cell of the row and sometimes I'll get an error message saying the object doesn't support pastespecial.

I can't tell if I'm messing up the copy by not specifying I mean copy the whole row or if I need to somehow to specify that the source data is from another workbook and the paste function should treat the data as a row's worth of data as opposed to a single cell's worth.

As noted, I copied the pastespecial line from a macro Excel generated when I used the "Record Macro" feature and performed the row copy manually.

In case it matters, here's the entire routine..

```
Sub copyStudentsToEmail(emailApacket)
' copies student records to email
Dim cel, nameCel, sourcePath As String
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Copy
sourcePath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)

Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.path & "\\email\\records.xls"

' search for bottom row
Range("a1").Select
While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Wend 

ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

' search for email cell
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
For Each cel In Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10))
  If cel Like "*@*" Then Exit For
Next
cel.Select

' if found email cell make adjustments
If (ActiveCell.Column < 10) Then
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
  Set nameCel = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
  ActiveCell.Value = Left(nameCel, InStr(nameCel, " ") - 1)
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
  cel = Right(nameCel, Len(nameCel) - Len(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)) - 1)
  ActiveCell.Value = Left(cel, InStr(cel, " ") - 1)
Else
  MsgBox ("Didn't find email address. Not sure how to adjust record.")
End If

If (emailApacket) Then sendApacket
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
Workbooks.Open sourcePath
End Sub
```

Comment: The macro is running in the workbook that you close, and it keeps running?? Am I missing something?

Comment: A.S.H There's a third workbook that contains the executing macro. That workbook stays open while the other workbooks open and close. I've updated the question to clarify that point.

Answer (score 1):

Many things in your macro can be improved, but briefly, if the problem is that sometimes the row gets pasted into one cell, try changing the part of copying/pasting into this:

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\\email\\records.xls"
Range("A32767").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial
```

ps: I use `A32767` because your target file seems to be from an Excel version prior to 2007, so I guess that the number of records should not reach that number.

Comment: Tried your approach and got a runtime 1004, pastespecial method of Range failed. Reading Microsoft's explanation it appears to be a version issue which you alluded to. I'll try just saving the spreadsheets in the new format and see if that fixes it.

Comment: A.S.H I had forgotten why I elected not to go to new format when I upgraded to 2010. I'm using the feature that supports dynamic menu creation which isn't supported by the newer file format.  Dynamic menu creation being dropped from Excel 2007 was why I skipped upgrading to Excel 2007.

Comment: So both source and destination files are pre-2007? What about the one running the macro?

Comment: I tested my code with two old-version files, it works fine but without the `xlPasteValues` parameter. Probably this one is the source of the error. Can you check?

Comment: Yeah, they're all 2003 versions.  I'll try saving the source and target workbooks in the new format but leave the macro container alone. Your version doesn't show xlPasteValues as a parameter. Do you mean add it?

Comment: No, I edited my answer to remove it. I tested the code on two old versions, it worked fine for me without the `xlPasteValues`, but when it is there, a runtime error occurs. Therefore I would like if you try again the code on your old files without the `xlPasteValues`.

Comment: Yep. It worked! Why does referencing a huge row number end up pasting at the end of the actual data on row 40  instead  and what's going on that is preferable to a range("a40").pastespecial instruction which I did try.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question, but it is good to know that on pre-2007 office, the row number is a 16-bit integer (VBA type Integer), so it is limited, while in 2007 and above the row number is 32 bits (VBA type Long)